# Mac Office Spell Checker API

Tags: macos, ms-office, spell-checking

I have all the documentation for how to develop and deploy proofing tools for MS Office on Windows using CSAPI, but how does one deploy them on Mac?

In 2010, [Eric Paquin](http://web.archive.org/web/20100815045409/http://www.officeformac.com/blog/I-know-I-ve-spelled-this-right) said Office 2011 for Mac would have the same API: "*3rd party proofing tools companies that are relying on Windows API can now port their tools to work on the Mac*"

But, I can't find any information regarding this. Anyone know where the docs for Mac development and deployment? Or if this never actually materialized?

And what about Mac Office 2016? I can find the [Office Add-ins stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220082.aspx), which unfortunately can't create integrated proofing tools.

(*[asked on Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/57b623c4-04e8-4b46-b29b-08bbcca675f8) ages ago, but nobody there knows*)

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you find any information regarding how to develop proofing tools for Office 2016 and later?

Comment: @birraa, yes, as I replied in the answer. It's not worth it to make native macOS Office-specific spellers. Either make a macOS OS-wide native speller, or make a portable Office.js add-in.

Comment: I am not interested in Mac, rather for Windows. As per your recommendation, I will try to contact Microsoft directly.

Answer (score 0):

Official Microsoft documentation does exist for deploying to MS Office for Mac. If you run into this problem, keep asking your MS contact about it.

Unfortunately I can't actually share the how, 'cause NDA. But, if you have tried reverse engineering this problem, it basically is as much of a mess as you discovered.